# How to say "the project that we are working on" in a short phrase?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, phrase-requests, hyphenation

I want a short phrase for "the project that we are working on".

Could it be "our working-on project"?

Comment: prevailing project

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say "Our current project." Or, in a little context, "We asked our supervisor if we could have more time to work on our current project."

Comment: In other contexts you might call it an **ongoing project**. Or even an **active** one.

Comment: In addition to what @FumbleFingers has mentioned, our **working project** is also a valid way of referring to this project.